# How to get events count from Microsoft Azure EventHub?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-eventhub

I want to get events count from Microsoft Azure EventHub.
I can use EventHubReceiver.Receive(maxcount) but it is slow on big number of big events.

There is NamespaceManager.GetEventHubPartition(..).EndSequenceNumber property that seems to be doing the trick but I am not sure if it is correct approach.

Comment: I'd like to clarify what you mean by "events count". 
Is that the total number of messages in the hub? in the partition? sent to the hub over a certain period of time? received from the hub over a certain period of time?

Comment: What would you want to do with the count?  Remember that the count is likely going to change immediately after getting it since you're talking about a service bus that should be processing lots of messages per second...

Comment: Yes, I want to get total number of messages in the hub. As long as I don't send new messages total number should be constant for a while - this is good enough for me.

Answer (score 13):

EventHub **doesn't have a notion of Message count**, as EventHub is a high-Throughput, low-latency durable **stream** of events on cloud - getting the CORRECT current count at a given point of time, could be wrong the very next milli-second!! and hence, it wasn't provided :)

Hmm, we should have named EventHubs something like a StreamHub - which would make this obvious!!

If what you are looking for is - how much is the Receiver lagging behind - then [`EventHubClient.GetPartitionRuntimeInformation().LastEnqueuedSequenceNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubClient_GetPartitionRuntimeInformation_System_String_) is your Best bet.

As long as no messages are sent to the partition this value remains constant :)

On the Receiver side - when a message is received - `receivedEventData.SequenceNumber` will indicate the Current sequence number you are processing and the **diff. between `EventHubClient.GetPartitionRuntimeInformation().LastEnqueuedSequenceNumber` and `EventData.SequenceNumber` can indicate how much the Receiver of a Partition is lagging behind** - based on which, the receiver process can Scale up or down the no. of Workers (work distribution logic).

[more on Event Hubs...](https://medium.com/@sreeramg/what-is-microsoft-azure-event-hubs-1ec100452067)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Stream Analytics**, with a simple query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    YourEventHub
GROUP BY
    TUMBLINGWINDOW(DURATION(hh, <Number of hours in which the events happened>))
```

Of course you will need to specify a time window, but you can potentially run it from when you started collecting data to now.

You will be able to output to **SQL/Blob/Service Bus** et cetera.

Then you can get the message out of the output from code and process it. It is quite complicated for a one off count, but if you need it frequently and you have to write some code around it, it could be the solution for you.

Comment: refrain from using this method. 1) This will potentially increase your EventHub bill - as you would read all events from EventHub (paying for events, network etc) and end up just getting the "count"! 2) less performant - will take long time!.