# record missing while uploading batch data to eventhub

Tags: python, azure-eventhub

Below is the code snippet which uploading data from delta table(total 8000 rows) to eventhub.
While counting the total uploaded rows from SeviceBus i found out that total 7999 records getting uploaded. Any suggestion?

```
df = spark.read.format('delta').load("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/x")
data_list = df.select("*").collect()

if not data_list:
  self.logger.error("No data available")
  raise Exception('Problem to send data')
list_of_dicts = []

for i in data_list:
 sub_dicts = {k:('%s'%v) for k,v in (i.asDict().items() if i else {})}
 list_of_dicts.append(sub_dicts)
  
total_messages = len(list_of_dicts)
batch = self.event_hub_client.create_batch(partition_id='0')
for i in range(total_messages):
  indv_msg = list_of_dicts[i]
  user_encode_data = json.dumps(indv_msg, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
  user_encode_data = str(user_encode_data)
  try:
    batch.add(EventData(user_encode_data))
  except ValueError:
    ship events
    self.event_hub_client.send_batch(batch)
    create batch
    batch = self.event_hub_client.create_batch(partition_id='0')
    i=i-1
  except Exception as e :
    self.logger.error("Error shipping event to EventHub: {}".format(e))

  if (i == total_messages - 1):
    self.event_hub_client.send_batch(batch)

self.event_hub_client.close()
self.logger.info("closing the client")
```

Comment: Hello @Saswat Ray, This may due to the your service bus is counting from 0.

Comment: You can also refer this thread which has dicussed for the same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818602/how-to-get-events-count-from-microsoft-azure-eventhub